# Tapping a view in xcode / swift 3 to 'select' it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, swift3

I'm looking to hone in on the methodology used to 'select' UIViews by a single tap. In my UI, I have several UIViews that I would like to be 'selectable.' While selected, I will have controls to perform basic adjustments such as alpha (to let the user know which view is selected), and slightly more advanced functionality such as revealing a unique set of menu items. Only 1 view may be selected at a time. No multi-touch here.

The problem is, I've only seen this done with UICollectionViewCells. My interface isn't utilizing a collection view, so that's out of the question.

Thought process going into this is 1 tap gesture to 'select' the uiview, and then 'deselecting' it by tapping outside of the views bounds.

Another thought process is going with UIButtons instead of UIViews to utilize the Selected state.

Which would be the more viable solution here? Is this even possible using just UIViews? Or should I backtrack and go UIButtons instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a gesture recognizer to the desired UIView

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

}
```

Then you need to add the Code to handle whatever happens to your UIView into the gesture recognizer function:

```
func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    myView.alpha = 0.5
}
```

This will change UIView's alpha property to 0.5 once the UIView gets selected.
[image] [image]

Now you could for example put a second UIView with a gesture recognizer and play with the alphas:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap2(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        secondView.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)

    }

    func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        myView.alpha = 0.5
        secondView.alpha = 1
    }

    func tap2(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        myView.alpha = 1
        secondView.alpha = 0.5
    }

}
```

That way, depending on the UIView you hit, the alpha will change...

[image] [image]

Edit:

In this Code the UIViews will be "selected" - the alpha will change and will change back within a set timing of 0.8 seconds.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap2(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        secondView.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)

    }

    func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        myView.alpha = 0.5
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: { 
            self.myView.alpha = 1
        })
    }

    func tap2(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        secondView.alpha = 0.5
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
            self.secondView.alpha = 1
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm at the moment opening xcode to translate it to swift 3

Comment: Thanks David! I have your code working. Just need to be able to "deselect" it (let's say, alpha goes back to 1). And only have 1 view selected at a time.

Comment: do you want the UIViews just to be selected for a second or something like that? or do you want the selection to stay? i can't help you if you're not talking to me bro

Comment: Just reading over your edits bro :)
I'd like for the selection to stay. There can also be X amount of views. Perhaps 1, or 4, or maybe 10. only ONE of the views can be selected at a time. if one is selected, and user taps off, it deselects. similarly, if one view is selected, and the user taps another view, the selections toggle.

Comment: okay so in my current code, there is only one view selected at a time. if you want the selection to end, you need to do something like follow: i will edit the code in a second

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve here is VERY similar to the game 'Memory' - in which two tiles are flipped to match objects on the bottom of the cards. The difference here is I am just flipping (toggling) one at a time.

Comment: now the views are "selected" and deselect automatically within a timeframe of 0.8 seconds.

Comment: We're closer... but I can't have the deselection on a timer. The toggling must be all user-controlled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125540/discussion-between-david-seek-and-joe).

Comment: i updated the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013332/getting-gestures-to-work-with-subclassed-uibutton